# Flash PNGEncoder using Vectors

Tags: flash, vector, bitmap, png, encode

There is great lib to convert `BitmapData` to JPEG using flash `Vector` instead of `Array`:

[Glitchmap](http://code.google.com/p/soulwire/source/browse/trunk/projects/Glitchmap/src_lib/com/pfp/utils?spec=svn6&r=6)

It is asynchronous, that's great as well.

Does anybody know similar solution for PNG encoding? Using Vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this article
http://moodycamel.com/blog/2011/a-better-png-encoder-for-flash

I found VERY fast asynchronous PNG encoder, compiled from Haxe:

https://github.com/cameron314/PNGEncoder2/

It helped me a lot.